# Is there a way to build a Remote Desktop Application in nodejs that runs on browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, remote-desktop

I want to build an application that runs on the browser to handle pc remotely, where the frontend is on Reactjs and the backend is on Nodejs. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to specifying what technologies you want to use, you should tell us why. What requirement are you trying to fill? You may not need React or Node.

Without Node, there are a few React components already made for noVNC:

- [react-vnc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-vnc)
- [react-vnc-display](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-vnc-display)

Those components require a VNC server. Here's a snippet from the noVNC readme:

> Server Requirements
>
> noVNC follows the standard VNC protocol, but unlike other VNC clients it does require WebSockets support. Many servers include support (e.g. x11vnc/libvncserver, QEMU, and MobileVNC), but for the others you need to use a WebSockets to TCP socket proxy. noVNC has a sister project websockify that provides a simple such proxy.

Source: [noVNC](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC#server-requirements)

Using Node, you could use the following packages:

- [guacamole-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/guacamole-lite)
- [node-rdpjs-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rdpjs-2)

You would then need to build a React component for the RDP/VNC display similar to `react-vnc` and `react-vnc-display`. `guacamole-lite` accepts websocket connections so you may be able to use one of those two React components with it.

Comment: thank you for your effort. the requirement is to control PC-2 from PC-1 using browser( web application). we don't want users to install any application. instead goto browser hit the URL share unique id and take control of PC-2 from PC-1.

Comment: @JavedSaifi did you ever solve this?  I'm looking for this exact thing right now.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @rom not exactly what I was expecting. but done it other way. I made desktop application using electron.js and registered it with custom protocol i.e remote-app://param1/param2/param3...... so, whenever user1(admin) need access to access user2 machine. then a custom protocol is called in user2 browser and that prompt to open desktop application. once application is opened then screen sharing starts automatically.
There are two drawback of this.
1. application should be installed in users machine
2. custom protocol should be always allowed

Comment: @JavedSaifi Wow, ok.  In my use case, I've got multiple users who do Windows Remote Desktop to run ecommerce accounts so we can avoid ip address issues.  But it's cumbersome having to login each time using normal ways.  Looking to just load up a web page and it just logs into a Windows Remote Desktop easily and painlessly.

Comment: Please note that node-rdpjs-2 license is GPL-3. There's also mstsc.js, but it uses node-rdpjs-2, so it also has the same license. I spent some time setting this up, then realized the licensing problem.